# How to control encoding in python library mailparser?

Tags: python, encoding, email-parsing

## Problem

I am using the python library [mailparser](https://pypi.org/project/mail-parser/) to handle ".msg" files in python. The library does, however, not seem to be able to handle different types of encoding. E.g. I cannot read the characters æ, ø, å in the body.

## Example

I have an e-mail with the text "This is a test of æ ø å", and when I use the library these letters just dissapear.

```
import mailparser

# Reading mail
mail = mailparser.parse_from_file_msg('/path/to/email/email.msg')

# Accessing body
mail.body
> 'This is a test of '
```

Comment: Use `parse_from_file_obj` and you can open the file object with whatever encoding you want

Comment: Would I first load the file into an object: file_obj = open('/path/to/email/email.msg') and then read that into the parser?

Comment: You probably want something like this: `with open(myfile, encoding='my-encoding') as file_obj: mail 
 = mailparser.parse_from_file_obj(file_obj)`

Comment: That I tried that, and if I change the encoding it just returns an empty mail.